# How to get a special character displayed

Tags: iphone, fonts

Other than a graphic, is there any way to display a special character?  (like add it to a font?)

I need something that looks like this, but takes only one line, not two:

_
/\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A font is really just a bunch of images that correspond with character values; however, I've heard of some font editing tools that would allow you to edit the characters directly.  If iphone lets you import your own fonts, that may be a working solution for you.